# GOENV can only be set using the OS environment

Tags: windows, go

I want to set the `GOENV` path and use the following command `go env -w GOENV=D:\go\env`, but he returns `go env -w: GOENV can only be set using the OS environment` how should I set the GOENV custom path?The computer environment of windows11

Comment: set GOENV=d:\go\env

Comment: @CetinBasoz This command does not report an error, but it does not take effect, it is still the original env path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What shell are you using ? cmd.exe or Powershell ?

In cmd.exe :

```
set GOENV=D:\go\env
```

In Powershell :

```
$env:GOENV="D:\go\env"
```